# Empty params hash after form is submit by capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

When i fill the form in using the code specified below (at Cucumber tests) and submit the one, my `params` hash comes with totally empty at controller.

I've done some debugging and at some deep level of Capybara, when it does actually sending, Nokogiri nodes do not have the `value` attribute set whils before the `click_button` call they do have.

```
visit '/'
click_link 'Sign out' if has_link? 'Sign out'
click_link 'Log in'

find(:css, '#user_email').set 'my@email.com'
find(:css, '#user_password').set 'foobar'
find(:css, '#user_remember_me').set true

click_button 'Sign in'
```

My `params` hash at controller:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign in", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"auth"}
```

The form HTML is something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="blah-blah-blah"></div>
<div class="email">
<label for="user_email" title="Email or LDAP username">Login</label>
:
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="EMAIL or LDAP" size="30" title="Email or LDAP username" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="password">
<label for="user_password">Password</label>
:
<input id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="PASSWORD" size="30" type="password">
</div>
<div class="rememberable">
<label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>
:
<div class="checkbox">
<input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">
</div>
</div>
<div class="signin">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="input">
Sign in
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

The output from running the `cucumber features/my_feature.feature -vb`:

```
shybovycha@shybovycha-laptop:~/projects/rails/my_project$ cucumber features/my_feature.feature -vb
Using the default profile...
Code:
  * features/support/env.rb
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
Clearing database
Running db:migrate
Running db:seed for our instance
  * features/support/capybara_headers.rb
  * features/step_definitions/backoffice.rb
  * features/step_definitions/content_verification .rb
  * features/step_definitions/db_manipulation.rb
  * features/step_definitions/forms_and_links.rb
  * features/step_definitions/jenkins_integration.rb
  * features/step_definitions/mobile_view.rb
  * features/step_definitions/navigation.rb
  * features/step_definitions/users_manipulation.rb

Features:
  * features/my_feature.feature
Parsing feature files took 0m0.135s

Feature: my_feature

  Scenario: do some actions               # features/my_feature.feature:3
    Given a logged in user                 # features/step_definitions/users_manipulation.rb:45
    And some data exists                      # features/step_definitions/db_manipulation.rb:12
    When I visit some page        # features/step_definitions/navigation.rb:13
    And click "Subscribe" link                      # features/step_definitions/forms_and_links.rb:6
      no link with title, id or text 'Subscribe' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:154:in `raise_find_error'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:27:in `block in find'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:54:in `wait_until'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:27:in `find'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:27:in `click_link'
      (eval):2:in `click_link'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:in `click_link'
      /home/shybovycha/projects/rails/my_project/features/step_definitions/forms_and_links.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_step_definition.rb:69:in `invoke'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:25:in `invoke'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:60:in `invoke'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:38:in `accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:99:in `block in visit_step'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:98:in `visit_step'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:15:in `block in accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `each'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:93:in `block in visit_steps'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:92:in `visit_steps'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in with_hooks'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:96:in `before_and_after'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `block in with_hooks'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `call'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `block (3 levels) in around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:in `block in around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:91:in `call'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:91:in `execute_around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in `around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:117:in `call'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:117:in `around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:91:in `around'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:78:in `with_hooks'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:53:in `block in accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:108:in `with_visitor'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:47:in `accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:51:in `block in visit_feature_element'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:50:in `visit_feature_element'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:43:in `block in accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:42:in `each'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:42:in `accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `block in visit_feature'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:19:in `visit_feature'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:29:in `block in accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `accept'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:14:in `block in visit_features'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `visit_features'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:46:in `run!'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
      /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
      /usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
      /usr/local/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
      features/my_feature.feature:7:in `And click "Subscribe" link'
...
```

That error shall tell you nothing except the content was not found. The reason is, `devise` does no authentication because **the `params` hash is empty**. So it could get no user data. So it could not authenticate one. So it does not let the user to view the page and redirects him to the homepage displaying the error message. So the content the test should use is not found.

Comment: Maybe you should use `fill_in`, example: `fill_in 'user_email', with: "my@email.com"`

Comment: Done already. Nothing helps.

Comment: your problem has solved?

Comment: Can you show the exact test fail message (and the rest of the test?).  When you do `click_button 'Sign in'` what results?  Also can we see the `UserController`?

Comment: @shybovycha try `page.find(:css, '#user_email').set 'my@email.com'` or `page.find('#user_email').set 'my@email.com'`

Comment: @joofsh in 1 .. 2 hrs, please. Assume controller is a Devise sessions controller and the first line at the `create` action only logs the `params` hash. More details coming soon

Comment: @KienThanh nothing happened. The error seems to be not in filling incorrect fields (assume there are no other fields to fill) but somewhere deeper. May be in the configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution and the reason of the issue.

### The reason

#### The short version

Somehow **Capybara** (even with **PhantomJS**) does not recognize if the element is visible or not. It's the internals of Capybara, not my tests.

#### Detailed reason description

See, we have two forms on one page - **signing up form** and **signing in form**. 
Both are hidden but when user hits either *sign in* or *sign up* button, correspondent form is shown.
Both forms contain fields **#user_email** and **#user_password**. 
But the *sign up form* contains **#user_password_confirmation** whilst *sign in* form contains **#user_remember_me** instead.

Just take a look at the code of the forms:

```
<div class="forms">
    <div class="signup-form" style="display: block;">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
            <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#10003;" />
                <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="viNleUNDfdlp92j9vVU9QravqMRbmCUZDqw3pV9jQK0=" />
            </div>

            <div class="email">
                <input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="EMAIL or LDAP" size="30" type="email" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="password">
                <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="PASSWORD" size="30" type="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="password">
                <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" placeholder="PASSWORD CONFIRMATION" size="30" type="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="signup">
                Sign up
                <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="signin-form" style="display: none;">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
            <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#10003;" />
                <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="viNleUNDfdlp92j9vVU9QravqMRbmCUZDqw3pV9jQK0=" />
            </div>

            <div class="email">
                <input autofocus="autofocus" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="EMAIL or LDAP" size="30" title="Email or LDAP username" type="text" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="password">
                <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="PASSWORD" size="30" type="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="rememberable">
                <label for="user_remember_me">Remember me</label>:

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" />
                    <input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="signin">
                Sign in
                <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, at the test there is a line that should make the **signing in form** visible. Then test tries to fill the **visible form** and send it to a server.

Yet, somewhy Capybara does not disticts the **visible form** and **the invisible one**. So it fills the inputs within the first form which is formely the **sign up** one.

Then there is a code line which clicks the **sign in button**. See? The filled in form is the **sign up** and the submit one is **sign in**.

### The solution

#### The short version

Do not use `fill_in 'Input', :with => 'value'`.

Use `find(:css, '#selector').set 'value'` or `find(:xpath, '/selector').set 'value'` instead.

#### The detailed description

As of the described reason, `fill_in` searches for **the first visible element matching the label/id/title given** *(`Input` in my example a few lines above)*.

If you may have a few inputs with the same label/id/title on one page but within different forms, the `fill_in` may be ambigious and fill the wrong element.

The `find` method searches for **the first element matching the selector rule given** *(`css selector` or `xpath`, basing on the first argument you've provided; `css selector` in my example above)*.

### Important note

So, **always try passing as much specific selector as it is possible**.