# Why are params not present when submitting a form with RSpec/Capybara?

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

This is on a Rails 7 app. We do our feature testing through RSpec and Capybara, using selenium chrome headless.

I have a form used to search for Request records, with a text field to search by name, and an accordion that opens up to reveal more specific filters, in this case: date of birth. Everything works nicely in the browser, but i can't get capybara to submit the form properly.

Here is the partial where I keep the form:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_with url: requests_path,
                method: :get,
                local: true,
                class: 'search-bar' do |f| %>

    <%= inline_svg_tag 'search.svg' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'search-field',
                            style: "width: #{field_width};",
                            placeholder: ' search by first, middle, or last name' %>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="accordion col-3 search-position" style="margin-left: <%= left_margin %>;" id="advancedFilters">
    <div class="accordion-item" style="width: 22vw;">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed search-accordion"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <span class="grey-text">Advanced filters</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne"
           class="accordion-collapse collapse"
           aria-labelledby="headingOne"
           data-bs-parent="#advancedFilters">
        <div class="accordion-body container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 text-left no-left-pad">
              <%= f.label :date_of_birth, 'Date of birth:', class: 'grey-text fs-6' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-left no-left-pad">
              <%= f.date_field :date_of_birth %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <%= f.submit 'Search', id: 'searchButton',
                           class: 'btn btn-primary search-btn',
                           onclick: "$('form').submit();",
                           data: {turbo: false} %>
  </div>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

I placed a byebug in the RequestsController#index action, and running the test revealed to me that the params hash was empty. However, if i submit the form myself on localhost, the params hash is populated as expected. Why are the params empty after Capybara submits the form?

Here's the capybara config file:

```rb
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'webdrivers/chromedriver'

Capybara.register_driver(:selenium_chrome_headless) do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.read_timeout = 120
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_emulation(device_metrics: {width: 1400,
                                         height: 800,
                                         touch: false})
  %w[headless disable-gpu].each do |option|
    options.add_argument(option)
  end

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome,
                                      options: options,
                                      http_client: client)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

The test:

```rb
RSpec.describe 'Searching for Requests', js: true do
  let!(:request1) {
    create(:request, user_id: user.id,
                     first_name: 'Cindy',
                     middle_name: 'Hill',
                     last_name: 'Baldwin',
                     date_of_birth: Date.parse('2000-05-18'))
  }

  let!(:request2) {
    create(:request, user_id: user.id,
                     first_name: 'Andrea',
                     middle_name: 'Marie',
                     last_name: 'Garcia',
                     date_of_birth: Date.parse('2000-05-17'))
  }

  let!(:request3) {
    create(:request, user_id: user.id,
                     first_name: 'Chauncey',
                     middle_name: 'Wynn',
                     last_name: 'Smith',
                     date_of_birth: Date.parse('2000-05-16'))
  }

  let!(:request4) {
    create(:request, user_id: user1.id,
                     first_name: 'Michelle',
                     middle_name: 'Ann',
                     last_name: 'Carey',
                     date_of_birth: Date.parse('2000-05-15'))
  }

  let!(:request5) {
    create(:request, user_id: user1.id,
                     first_name: 'James',
                     middle_name: 'Artur',
                     last_name: 'Tyrell',
                     date_of_birth: Date.parse('2000-05-14'))
  }
  describe 'advanced filters' do
    before do
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
      fill_in :user_password, with: user.password
      click_button 'Log in'
      page.find_by_id('advancedFilters').click 
    end

    it 'can search by date of birth' do
      fill_in :date_of_birth, with: '05-18-2000'
      click_button 'Search'

      expect(page).to have_css "li#request-#{request1.id}"

      not_matched = [request2, request3, request4, request5]
      not_matched.each do |r|
        expect(page).not_to have_css "li#request-#{r.id}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have already tried:

- using find with selectors instead of fill_in, based on the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420635/empty-params-hash-after-form-is-submit-by-capybara?newreg=407726089cfa4a48bd3c8ce16e7d163e):

```rb
find('input#date_of_birth').set '05-18-2000'
find('button#searchButton').click
```

- using plain javascript to submit the form:

```rb
fill_in :date_of_birth, with: '05-18-2000'
find('form').execute_script('this.submit();')
```

- adding `local: true` and/or `remote: true` to the form_with call
- I double checked to make sure all my html is valid; all the </div> and <% end %> tags look fine to me

#### Solution - solved by the first commenter

It turns out having the `form_with` and `end` inside of different divs was causing strange behavior. Refactoring the whole form to be inside of the accordion-body div fixed my issue:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="accordion col-3 search-position" style="margin-left: <%= left_margin %>;" id="advancedFilters">
    <div class="accordion-item" style="width: 22vw;">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed search-accordion"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <span class="grey-text"><%= inline_svg_tag 'search.svg' %>Find a beneficiary</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne"
           class="accordion-collapse collapse"
           aria-labelledby="headingOne"
           data-bs-parent="#advancedFilters">
        <div class="accordion-body container">
          <%= form_with url: requests_path,
                        method: :get,
                        local: true,
                        class: 'search-bar' do |f| %>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col text-left">
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'search-field full-width', placeholder: ' first, middle, or last name' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col text-left">
                <%= f.label :date_of_birth, 'Date of birth:', class: 'grey-text fs-6' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col text-left">
                <%= f.date_field :date_of_birth, class: 'grey-text search-field' %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col text-left">
                <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary search-btn half-width',
                                       onclick: "$('form').submit();",
                                       data: {turbo: false} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try sleeping for a second or two before clicking the search button to make sure it’s not a JS widget issue. Also Youre mot showing all the before steps of your test, since there’s no visit, etc. Additionally your template will produce invalid HTML since Youre starting the form inside a div but ending it outside of that div which could cause all sorts of strange behavior

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWalpole, Moving the `form_with` and `end` into the same div solved the issue. Gonna update the post to include the solution, and in the future I'll avoid splitting a form into multiple divs. Thanks again!